# PHP, display message if one or more fields is empty

Tags: php

What I want is to show the error (message), only if the user do a false action. For example, if the field is empty, it will show (Please fill all the fields). I've already done that, but the problem that I have is that it shows also if the user enter to the page for the first time, meaning it does NOT respects the (if condition) that I have written !

### The question :

How to show the message only if one of the fields is empty ?

Any ideas on how I can solve it ?

Here is my code :

> ```
>    <?
>    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'db', 'db_pass', 'db_name') or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn)); 
>    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
>    $old_password = trim($_POST['old_pass']);
>    $new_password = trim($_POST['new_pass']);
>    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);
>    $old_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$old_password);
>    $new_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$new_password);
>    if(empty($email) || empty($old_password) || empty($new_password)){
>    echo 'Please fill all the fields !<br>';
>    }
>    else{
>    $sql="UPDATE users SET pass='$new_password' WHERE email='$email' AND pass='$old_password'" or     die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn));
>    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
>    mysqli_close($conn);
>    }
>    if($result){
>    echo'Password changed successfully !';
>    }
>    elseif(!$result) {
>    echo 'The email/password you provided is false !';
>    }
>    ?>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Validation of any form  happens in the "action" file within a condition i.e. the validation should be subjected to the event of user clicking the submit button. For this to work you should check that

```
  1. Your form has a submit button with a name property set to say submit (can be anything)

eg: <input type="submit" name="submit" id="someid" value="Submit" />

  2. The form must have action property pointing to a processor file

eg: <form action = "somefile.php" method = "post">

  3. In the somefile.php file the validation code must be within a condition which checks for the event of form been submited

eg://somefile.php

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']{
      //all the validation code goes here
  }else{
  //for a single page form and validation
  // the code for displaying the form can go here
?>
```

Comment: Your code seems to miss just wrapping the validation code within the condition to check whether the form has been submitted or not. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to do this:

- First define a variable with plain $_POST[] for eg $name = $_POST['name'];
- Then, check if all the vatiables you've define are empty or not.
- Lastly, Use escape_string() or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to check for a variable that you know will *always* be set if the form is submitted, usually the submit button.
For example, if your form ends like this:

```
  ... 
  <input type="submit" name="change_password" value="Change password" />
</form>
```

then in the PHP code you could check

```
if(isset($_POST['change_password'])) {
  // The submit button was in the POSTed data, so this is a form submit
} else {
  // This is a new page load
}
```

Alternatively, if you are `POST`ing the data, you can check which HTTP method was used to call the form:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  // Form was posted
} else {
  // $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET'
}
```

The pattern I commonly use is:

```
$showForm = true;
if( is_form_postback() ) { 
  if( data_is_valid() ) {
    redirect_to_thank_you_page();
  } else {
    show_validation_errors();
    $showForm = false;
  }
}

if($showForm) {
  // Print the form, making sure to set the value of each input to the $_POSTed value when available.
}
```